# Running multiple tests developed in Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, web-applications, selenium, concurrency, selenium-ide

Alright, I've made a test for a web application that runs well. However, to simulate a lot of people using the application at once, I want to somehow run a bunch of the same tests on the application concurrently. I'm pretty sure you can't do this with the Selenium IDE, but is there a way I can use the test I developed in the IDE, take it into perhaps another selenium testing tool that allows me to run multiple tests concurrently?

PS. New to Selenium and webapp testing in general so sorry for the noob question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was something called selenium gird I think.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is [NeuStar's performance testing](http://www.neustar.biz/enterprise/web-performance#) formerly BrowserMob. There is [a blog post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/load-testing-xaf-part-3-uploading-and-validating-the-virtual-user-script/) describing a typical test here. The Neustar tests are not free, but very low cost (approx USD 4.00 for a 25 user test for an hour).

The technology behind the Neustar performance testing is the open source [BrowserMob tool](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy) which is harder to get running but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

selenium consist three components as Selenium IDE, Selenium2 i.e. Selenium webdriver & selenium Grid.

1. selenium IDE :-  It is mainly used for Record & playback, bunch of testcases can be execute using the Test Suite.
2. Selenium 2 :- It is one of the powerful tool for Automation testing see the following link, http://chetanselenium.blogspot.in/2013/02/whyselenium-itis-interesting-question.html
3. selenium Grid:-  it is mainly used for server side test execution.

Comment: Ah I see. But does selenium 2 (web driver) allow simultaneous test execution?

Comment: you mean Data driven test execution?

Comment: As i mansion web-driver is powerful tool for functional automation testing in which we can pass the different data for same script via excel, csv file & achive data driven testing.  As well as with the help of Grid same test can store on server & run across different machine with different browser simultaneously.